# EF Code First Migration list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I want to see all available of migrations in a project. Command Get-Migrations returns all applied migrations to DB, but I want to see all migration list, including not applied. Reason : I have created one more migration in the project and want to remove it. I removed files of migration, but Visual Studio (solution) remember of this migration and want to apply it.

[image]

Where is 201706071156593_AutomaticMigration at all and how to remove it?

Comment: What do you have set in your configuration for AutomaticMigrationsEnabled and AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the files should be sufficient - have you built the project since?

You can programmatically access the list of migrations using the [DbMigrator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.113).aspx) class, which has a method `GetPendingMigrations()` which will return the name of all migrations which it is aware of that have not yet been applied.

**Update**: Now that you've updated your question with the migration name, it becomes clear that because you have Automatic Migrations enabled (in the constructor of Configuration), this is the cause.  To use explicit migrations only, change `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to false.

Comment: I deleted from Visual Studio

Comment: But if you deleted the files and didn't build the project after, then they are still compiled into the output and will be run.

Comment: but project can be compiled :)

Comment: With automatic migrations enabled it's just going to keep coming back.